# Make UITableViewHeaderFooterView non sticky

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I am having a common footer for all cells and I am setting it with

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

I know that by default footers are sticky to bottom of UITableView, I dont want footers to stick to bottom of table, what is best way to achieve this?

One way I know is to add extra row and show footer there, But I am looking for cleaner approach than this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11):

You can set `UITableViewStyle` as `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Use this initializer.

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;
```

You can set this on storyboard.

[image]

Comment: I am using storyboards so I think i need to change style from storyboard

Comment: It added a separator at the top :(

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extra `uitableviewcell` and append at the last of tableview. In the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method you can add one 1 like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [objectArray count]+1 ;
 }
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         if(indexpath.row  == [objectArray count]) {
          //create footer cell
        }
        else {
        //show normal cell
       }
    }
```

Comment: suhit's answer is correct. A table view footer is meant to stick, and trying to prevent that would be hacky. The best way to get extra content under a cell without sticking is another cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have static height for footer and not changing the `contentInsets`, you can try this (assuming footer height is 44):

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -44, 0)
```